# EF Core ThenInclude foreign key values with 1:n relationshop

Tags: c#, entity-framework, linq, ef-core-2.2

I have a `Transaction`that has multiple `TransactionLines`. A transactionLine has a `SubCategory`, and a SubCategory has a `Category`.

I am trying to get a list of transactions. I want to be able to list the transaction, along with the Category it's assigned to. Usually a Transaction has one TransactionLine, but can have multiple, with each Line have different categories.

I am trying to do this in my client side Linq statement, but my Includes are letting me down.

```
        var data = context.Transaction
            .Include(x => x.CreditAccount)
            .Include(x => x.DebitAccount)
            .Include(x => x.TransactionLines)
            .ThenInclude(x=>x.TransactionLines.SubCategory)
            .ThenInclude(x=>x.TransctionLines.SubCategory.Category)
            .Include(x => x.Budget)
```

The `ThenInclude` lines are incorrect. It doesn't offer `SubCategory`. Only `Sum`, `First` etc.

I am trying to achieve:

```
SELECT 
FROM Transaction t
INNER JOIN TransactionLine tl ON tl.TransactionId = t.Id
INNER JOIN SubCategory sc ON sc.Id = tl.SubCategoryId
INNER JOIN Category c ON c.Id = sc.CategoryId
```

But I can't seem to get the SubCategory part right.

My TransactionLine class has a SubCategory object.

```
 public virtual Subcategory Subcategory { get; set; }
```

But it seems I cannot access this. Any help would be great.

**Entities:**

Transaction:

```
internal class Transaction 
    {
        [Key, Required, Column(Order = 1)]
        public int Id { get; set; }

        [Required, Column(Order = 2)]
        public Guid ExternalId { get; set; }

        [Required, Column(TypeName = "date", Order = 3)]
        public DateTime Date { get; set; }

        [Column(Order = 4)]
        public string Description { get; set; }

        [Required, Column(Order = 3), InverseProperty("TransactionDebitAccount")]
        public virtual Account DebitAccount { get; set; } // Nav

        [Required, Column(Order = 4), InverseProperty("TransactionCreditAccount")]
        public virtual Account CreditAccount { get; set; } // Nav

        [Required]
        public virtual List<TransactionLine> TransactionLines { get; set; } //Nav
    }
```

TransactionLine

```
internal class TransactionLine
    {
        [Key, Required, Column(Order = 0)]
        public int Id { get; set; }

        [Required, Column(Order = 1)]
        public Guid ExternalId { get; set; }

        [Required, Column(Order = 2)]
        public virtual Transaction Transaction { get; set; } // Nav 

        [Column(Order = 5), Range(0.01, 999999.99, ErrorMessage = "Amount must be between 0.01 and 999,999.99")]
        public decimal Amount { get; set; }

        [Column(Order = 6)]
        public virtual Budget Budget { get; set; }

        [Column(Order = 7)]
        public virtual Subcategory Subcategory { get; set; }

    }
```

SubCategory

```
internal class Subcategory : EntityAudit
{
    [Required, Key]
    public int Id { get; set; }

    [Required]
    public Guid ExternalId { get; set; }

    [Required, StringLength(30, MinimumLength = 2, ErrorMessage = "Subcategory Name must be between 2 and 30 charactors")]
    public string Name { get; set; }

    [Required]
    public Category Category { get; set; }
}
```

Comment: can you show your entities?

Comment: Added entities.

Comment: can you try `.Include(x => x.TransactionLines.Select(c => c.Category);`? Will it work?

Comment: Interesting. That seemed to allow the code to compile. Cannot run right now, as there are other errors, but the compiler says that works. Strange. Why would that be?

Comment: edited my answer and mark it as answer if it helps :)

Comment: I get runtime error now though: : 'The Include property lambda expression 'x => {from TransactionLine c in x.TransactionLines select [c].Subcategory}' is invalid. The expression should represent a property access: 't => t.MyProperty'. To target navigations declared on derived types, specify an explicitly typed lambda parameter

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try the following:

```
.ThenInclude(x=>x.Subcategory)
.ThenInclude(x=>x.Category)
```

[ThenInclude()](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.entityframeworkcore.entityframeworkqueryableextensions.theninclude?view=efcore-2.1) "works" with the previously selected property, which in your case is `TransactionLine` in the first case, and `Subcategory` in the second case.

Don't mind AutoComplete not giving you the correct properties of TransactionLine/Subcategory. In this case I think it gets confused by the 2 ThenInclude() overloads.

Comment: The name of the property should be `Subcategory` instead of `SubCategory`.

Comment: Wow, very good spot! The 'Subcategory' case worked! So this is an intellisense issue with linq/ef core?

Comment: Probably not really an issue... There's 2 overloads of ThenInclude() which are almost identical and I think intellisense just chooses the first one it finds (which is unfortunately not the one acting on the selected property object).